# Oracle compare two numbers in select

Tags: oracle, plsql, execute-immediate

I would like to execute pl sql query below and get result of the comparison.

```
 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE  'select 5<6 FROM DUAL' ;
```

Executing error is something like below:

```
ORA-06550: line 1, column 18:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "select 5<6 FROM DUAL" when expecting one of the following:

   := . ( @ % ;
The symbol ":=" was substituted for "select 5<6 FROM DUAL" to continue.
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action
```

:

My math operator between two numbers is dynamic , meaning it can be any other operator like < , > , <=, >=, =  etc.   And it comes from parameter  to my stored procedure.

For Instance :
There is 3  in parameters in my SP.
number1  , number2 and math operator.

Actually what am ı looking for is somith like eval() function in javascript which is automatically execute string operation  and return its result .  Eval("5<3")

Comment: What result are you expecting?

Comment: @WilliamRobertson true or false

Comment: The words 'true' or 'false', displayed on the screen? That won’t happen because SQL has no Boolean type, and in any case I don’t see any code to capture and display the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one option:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> declare
  2    retval varchar2(20);
  3  begin
  4    execute immediate q'[select case when 5 < 6 then 'true'
  5                                     else 'false'
  6                                end
  7                         from dual]'
  8            into retval;
  9
 10    dbms_output.put_Line('Result: ' || retval);
 11  end;
 12  /
Result: true

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my working code sample.

```
execute immediate 'select case when ' || SQL1R  || item.operator||  SQL2R || ' then  1 else 0 end from dual'  INTO COMP;
```

Thanks to @Littlefoot